# Unable to connect to MongoDB when using a URI with credentials

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm trying to build a simple CRUD API with the MongoDB Rust driver but I'm failing to insert anything into the DB. I'm using Mlab to host my database.

The code that I'm running:

```
#[macro_use(bson, doc)]
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;

use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};

fn main() {
    let client = Client::with_uri(
        "mongodb://<my_db_username>:<my_db_password>@ds235711.mlab.com:35711/rustcrud",
    )
    .expect("Failed to initialize client");

    let coll = client.db("rustcrud").collection("test");

    coll.insert_one(doc! { "title": "Back to the Future" }, None)
        .unwrap();
}
```

And the error that I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: OperationError("not authorized on rustcrud to execute command { insert: \"test\", $db: \"rustcrud\" }")', libcore/result.rs:1009:5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `not authorized on rustcrud to execute command { insert: \"test\", $db: \"rustcrud\" }")` — your credentials are bad.

Answer (score 2):

From the project's GitHub repository, [issue 256: Add auth to base examples](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-rust-driver-prototype/issues/256)

> user-password authentication occurs at the database-level. The user, password, and database are parsed from the URI, but I don't believe we have it set up to automatically authenticate when you create the database object

```
let client = Client::with_uri("mongodb://x:y@localhost:27017")?;
client.auth("x", "y");
```

Comment: Oh that really is embarrassing. Well it "is" a prototype, and we see why. Worth adding that the same is true for the "database" namespace on the uri as given in the question as this also needs to be omitted. The credentials "should" be stored within the `admin` database, which is where that `auth()` method and all default authentication is actually done. Unless explicitly told otherwise.